# How do you get rid of the bullets in the Angular-Bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get rid of the bullets in the Angular-bootstrap modal.  You can see the demo code here:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/iv9KjOW2CIfRUZW7y8sP?p=preview
```

Here is a portion of the sample in questions:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

If you click the modal and open it there are bullet points next to the items in the modal.  I want to change these and whether the items are aligned right, left, justified or centered.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview isn't going to link properly.  Should be a code specific to your plunkr...

Comment: Change the list styling?

Comment: Apologies on the plunkr link I edited above. http://plnkr.co/edit/iv9KjOW2CIfRUZW7y8sP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this custom CSS. Targets all the unordered lists inside modal box.

```
.modal-body ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3t4MtG0BcpThNB6F8OTc?p=preview)

Comment: Haha :D It is. Regarding **whether the items are aligned right, left, justified or centered** you can use text-right, text-left, text-center classes of Bootstrap with the list items.